# How to get OneSignal Push Notification Device ID Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

I have implemented the push notification functionality in my ionic app but it is not working. I am not getting the register id after the app is deployed. Following is my code.

app.component.ts

```
 constructor(public platform: Platform, public splashScreen: SplashScreen, public menu: MenuController,
 private storage: StorageService,private toast: ToastService, public events: Events, private push: Push,
  private alertCtrl: AlertController, public network: Network, private api: UserService) {
platform.ready().then(() => {

  debugger
  this.pushSetup();


  this.userDetails = this.storage.getData('userDetails');
  this.isAlertShown = false;
  // this.task = setInterval(() => {
  //   this.checkInternet();
  // }, 3000);
  if (this.userDetails != undefined || this.userDetails != null) {
    this.rootPage = 'welcome';
  } else {
    this.rootPage = 'login';
  }
  this.initializeApp();
});
```

pushSetup() {

```
console.log("inside pushSetup");

const options: PushOptions = {

  android: {
    senderID: '592660866764',
    forceShow: 'true'

  },
  ios: {
    alert: 'true',
    badge: true,
    sound: 'false'
  }
};
console.log("inside pushSetup 1");
const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);


pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));

pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) =>console.log('Received a notification', registration));




pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
 ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
 npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal
```

insert in `app.module.ts` `Onesignal`

```
import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal';

    providers: [
    ....
      OneSignal
    ...
    ]
```

In App Component you needs [One Signal App ID](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/accounts-and-keys#section-keys-ids) and [Google Project ID](http://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard)

in `app.component.ts`:

```
import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

 constructor(public oneSignal: OneSignal,
    private platform: Platform) { }

 onseSignalAppId: string = 'YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID';
 googleProjectId: string = 'YOUR_GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID';


  if(this.platform.is('cordova')) {
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
            this.oneSignal.startInit(this.onseSignalAppId, this.googleProjectId);
      }
      else if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
            this.oneSignal.startInit(this.onseSignalAppId);
      }
    this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);

    this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(() => {
                // do something when notification is received
    });

    this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(result => {
                // do something when a notification is opened 
    });

    this.oneSignal.endInit();

    // AND THIS METHOD RETURN YOUR DEVICES USER_ID

    this.oneSignal.getIds().then(identity => {
      alert(identity.pushToken + ' it's PUSHTOKEN'); 
      alert(identity.userId + 'it's USERID);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and answer . I have my google project id but i don't have onesignalid .

Comment: The last method this.oneSignal.getIds() will return me onesignalId

Comment: First of all you need create OneSignal App

Comment: @Gurbela Can I getIds into home.ts page? I want to check everytime when user come to home page. Is it possible?